# Codename One: User interface layout on simulator and a real Android device are complete different

Tags: codenameone

Well, it is the first time I tested my app on a real Android device. The user interface layout is shockingly different from the simulator. Please see images:

[image]

[image]

The code are the same and nothing had been modified.

Android version is 5.1.1.

The code to display the screen is:

```
    private final void show() {
    loginSignupForm = new Form(null, new BorderLayout());
    Tabs loginSignupTabs = new Tabs();
    Image splashScreenImage = theme.getImage("Starlent_logo25x25.png");
    ((Label) loginSignupForm.getToolbar().getTitleComponent()).setIcon(splashScreenImage);
    Style loginSignupStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
    prepareAndAddSignupTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    prepareAndAddLoginTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    loginSignupForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, loginSignupTabs);
    loginSignupForm.show();
}
```

So, how do I manage or expect the layout to be in different devices?

At the very least, I hope to have the logo placed in the center of the Android device. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi, during the "New Project" creation phase did you select "Native Theme" template? It seems the theme that you are using adapts to the OS platform of the device. Therefore the simulator has an iOS device & iOS theme, and Android device has Android native theme, hence the layouts are different (these are the default OS standards). You can override all these settings. Quickest way is to use a different theme, by opening the Resource Editor (theme.res) file. And adding an existing Red, Blue or Business theme.

Comment: Yes, I did specifically selected the native theme. So, in other words, I have to let it adapt to the default theme of the platform. And what about centering the logo? If I can center the logo, it would be fine (assuming no more surprises in my other screens).

Comment: It looks like the emulator is iPhone and the screenshot of real device is of Android. Is it the reason for the difference? I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the native theme, if you install an Android skin you will see that the theme behaves that way on the simulator too as this is intentional.

Your theme and code can override platform specific behavior to produce identical results e.g. override tab placement etc. The app won't feel as native on Android though if the tabs are on the bottom.