# Simulator is different to IPhone

Tags: codenameone

I'm setting buttons, textfields and a picture so that there is a perfect looking on simulator IPhone6. 
Then I put it on a real IPhone 6, there are some differences.
The picture isn't central, one button is half outside.
I program it by hand with no gui builder.
What is the best way, to set buttons, labels, textfields ... so that they are
correctly placed on hardware?

here my sample code:

```
Form dlgpass = new Form("");
    dlgpass.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Image img2;
    try {
        img2 = Image.createImage("/xz.jpg");
        Container cco2 = BoxLayout.encloseX();
        Label llc1 = new Label(" ");
        Label llc2 = new Label(" ");

        cco2.getStyle().setMarginBottom(50);
        cco2.getStyle().setMarginTop(20);
        cco2.add(llc1).add(img2).add(llc2);
        dlgpass.add(cco2);
        Label ll4 = new Label("        ");
        Label ll5 = new Label("    ");

        Container cco3 = BoxLayout.encloseX();
        Label llc3 = new Label(„test");
        cco3.getStyle().setMarginTop(100);
        cco3.add(ll4).add(llc3).add(ll5);

        Container cco4 = BoxLayout.encloseX();
        TextField pa = new TextField("", "Password", 16, TextField.PASSWORD);
        Label ll6 = new Label("   ");
        Label ll7 = new Label("     ");
        cco4.getStyle().setMarginTop(60);
        cco4.add(ll6).add(pa).add(ll7);
        dlgpass.add(cco4);

        Button logi = new Button("          login          ");
        logi.addActionListener((e) -> chlogi(pa.getText(),ce));

        Label ll1 = new Label("              ");
        Label ll2 = new Label("        ");       
        Container cco1 = BoxLayout.encloseX();
        cco1.getStyle().setMarginTop(60);
        cco1.add(ll1).add(logi).add(ll2);
        dlgpass.add(cco1);
```

The picture is 629x810 pixels with 24bit color.
This is a Splashscreen to login.

The pictures:

[image: Simulator picture]

[image: Iphone 6 picture]

EDIT
Chen, this is what I tried. Is it what you meant?

```
Form dlgpass = new Form("", new BorderLayout());
            Image img2;
            img2 = Image.createImage("/xx.jpg");
            ScaleImageLabel simg = new ScaleImageLabel(img2);
            dlgpass.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, simg);
            Container cco = new Container(new BorderLayout());
            TextField pa = new TextField("", "Password", 16, TextField.PASSWORD);
            cco.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,pa);
            FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER);
            flow.setValign(Component.BOTTOM);
            Container cco1 = new Container(flow);
            Button logi = new Button("       login       ");
            logi.addActionListener((e) -> chlogi(pa.getText(),ce));
            cco1.addComponent(logi);
            cco.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,cco1);
            dlgpass.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,cco);
```

Comment: We will need pictures and some code samples that differ it could be because of this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-material-buttons.html but based on your description it's more a matter of density.

Comment: The code and the pictures I will (can) provide later. 
When I think on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887456/codename-one-user-interface-layout-on-simulator-and-a-real-android-device-are-c?rq=1) ,
Is there a way to set a button with x y coordinates by percentage to the screen width and height. 
If so, there would be no problems in IOS and Android and other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid spaces, empty labels, setting margins on components use layouts to position the components on the From.
In your use case I would probably do something like this:

- Form - BorderLayout.

  - ScaleImageLabel - center
  - Container(BorderLayout) - south

    - TextField - north
    - Container(FlowLayout center) - south

      - Button

if you need/want to space the components use setUIID() on the Components and in the theme adjust the margins and/or paddings (always use mm)

Comment: I'll try to fix it with your hints. It looks very useful. Thanks for experienced info.

Answer (score 1):

To understand layout positioning portability check out this video https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---positioning-components-using-layout-managers.html on using layout managers effectively.

Also check out Multi-Image which allow images to adapt to various sizes.

Comment: I still check the link you gave.
The sample code you ask for is now in the question.

By the way: thanks for great great help!

Comment: Did Chen's answer resolve the issue? If so you need to accept it or ask clarifying questions so we'll know...

Comment: Shai, please hold on, I try to code it with Chens hints now. But this is not the only project to code in the moment.